# How to use tab separators with grep in ash or dash script?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, dash-shell, ash

Task at hand:

I have a file with four tab separated values:

```
peter 123   five   apples
jane  1234  four   rubberducks
jimmy 01234 seven  nicknames
```

I need to get a line out of this file based on second column, and the value is in a variable. Let's assume I have number 123 stored in a variable foo. In bash I can do

```
grep $'\s'$foo$'\s'
```

and I get out of peter's info and nothing else. Is there a way to achieve the same on dash or ash?

Comment: `grep "[[:space:]]${foo}[[:space:]]"` invokes grep with an equivalent regex without using any bash-only features. `\s`, by the way, is intended to be passed with the backslash to your grep command literally, not interpreted by the shell, and is only for cases where you have a PCRE-compliant grep (which most aren't); using `[[:space:]]` is the better practice, whatever your shell.

Comment: ...that said, it's "equivalent" to a quite bad practice, as you're substituting in content which will be interpreted as a regex, not as a raw string. For numbers that's harmless; for arbitrary content, not so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk` here:

```
var='1234'
awk -v var="$var" '$2 == var ""' f
jane  1234  four   rubberducks
```

**PS:** I am doing `var ""` to make sure `var` is treated as a string instead of as a number.

Comment: Thanks. I tested your suggestion on dash CLI, and got out both peter and jane, so it looks like that only accounts for the first tab. Or did I do something wrong?

I used \s instead of \t in my script as I understand that's for general whitespace, which makes it more flexible. The reason I want to find this out is twofold... firstly I want to stray away from bashism as much as I can, secondly I work with devices that contain busybox, which means ash shell.

Comment: Sorry I had a typo, it is fixed now. Try again.

Comment: Well that starts to work better :-) Even when I replace 123 with the actual variable (var=$var instead of var='123') it works. However when I set var='1234' or use the actual variable with value 1234 it returns both jane and jimmy. Does dash treat leading zero as a whitespace or something?

Comment: Oops... as a clarification I wasn't inferring there's BASHism in your suggestion. Just the fact that there well may be some in mine :)

Comment: It is because it is doing numerical comparison and `1234` is same as `01234`. If you want string comparison see my updated answer above.

Comment: Awesome! And that doesn't seem to care whether the whitespace is tabs or spaces. Thanks a 10^6 :-) Awk's really an awesome tool...

Answer (score 0):

If your file is small enough that the inefficiency of doing iteration in a shell doesn't matter, you don't actually need `grep` for this at all. The following is valid in any POSIX-compliant shell, including ash or dash:

```
var=123
while read -r first second rest; do
  if [ "$second" = "$var" ]; then
    printf '%s\t' "$first" "$second"; printf '%s\n' "$rest"
  fi
done
```

(In practice, I'd probably use awk here; consider the demonstration just that).